# C - Printing Variables within Strings

Tags: c

Is it possible to include variables through using `%c` and such when you have strings saved into the array?

```
char *MainMenuNames[] = { "%c - Move Left", "%c - Move Right","%c - Move Up","%c - Move Down","%c - Back","%c - Confirm","%c - Show Stats","%c - Show Inventory","%c - Show Legend","%c - Show Controls"};
```

When I have something like this, is it possible to put something into the `%c`?

Comment: Use it as a format string to [`sprintf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf), maybe?

Comment: That's exactly what the `printf` family of functions does. printf itself prints to stdout, but you can print to a file, or even just assemble a string with `snprintf` and do with it what you like.

Comment: printf and such are runtime functions. You can't achieve their effect at compile time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the array element as a parameter to formatting functions like `printf()`

```
char *commands = "lrudbcsiln";
for (int i; i < strlen(commands); i++) {
    printf(MainMenuNames[i], commands[i]);
    putchar('\n');
}
```